# Store last value added to rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, message-queue

I am new to rabbitmq and I want to configure it to just store the last value added to a queue. How can I configure this in order to store just the last value

If this isn't posible what queue I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ is a queues system, you cannot store only the "last" value. It stores all the messages as FIFO

I'd suggest to start with the basic AMQP concepts:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, I know it is a FIFO. I need a queue that only maintains the last value added to it. If it's any configuration to do this with rabbitmq.

Comment: By default there is not this kind of the queue, you need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Although what you try to do doesn't seem to fit a standard use of messaging systems like RabbitMQ, I guess you could get the desired behavior by configuring the [queue length](https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html) to 1

> The default behaviour for RabbitMQ when a maximum queue length or size is set and the maximum is reached is to drop or dead-letter messages from the front of the queue (i.e. the oldest messages in the queue).

So defining a queue with length 1 means only the latest message is kept.

Comment: Can you recommend me other queue?

Comment: What do you mean by other queue?

Comment: If you can recommend me another queue to store only one value, the last one.

Comment: I'd recommend another tool altogether 
Tools designed to keep value/pair information seem to be a better fit to your need.

Such as etcd or equivalent.

My proposal was a "hack" of sort to use rabbitmq for this need, but to "keep" the value there you'd need to read the message containing it and then requeue it, which is definitely not a logic you should setup in a messaging system. It's just not what they are supposed to be used for.